# Create a proper date variable from an existing date variable in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame 'rta' with a date variable (date of death) with data entered in multiple formats like DD/MM/YY, D/M/YY, DD/M/YY, D/MM/YY, DD/MM, D/MM, D/M, DD/M.

`rta$date.of.death<-c('12/12/08' ,'1/10/08','4/3/08','24/5/08','23/4','11/11','1/12')`

Luckily all the dates belong to the year 2008.
I want to make this variable into a uniform format of DD/MM/YYYY, for example 12/12/2008. How to get it this way?

Comment: What's the last format 'DM/M' ?

Comment: It was mistyped. I have made the change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this quick'n'dirty way:

```
rta <- data.frame(date.of.death=c('12/12/08' ,'1/10/08', '4/3/08',
                                  '24/5/08','23/4','11/11','1/12'),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

# append '/08' to the dates without year
noYear <- grep('.+/.+/.+',rta$date.of.death,invert=TRUE)
rta$date.of.death[noYear] <- paste(rta$date.of.death[noYear],'08',sep='/')

# convert the strings into POSIXct dates
dates <- as.POSIXct(rta$date.of.death, format='%d/%m/%y')
# turn the dates into strings having format: DD/MM/YYYY
rta$date.of.death <- format(dates,format='%d/%m/%Y')

> rta$date.of.death
[1] "12/12/2008" "01/10/2008" "04/03/2008" "24/05/2008" "23/04/2008" "11/11/2008" "01/12/2008"
```

Note:
this code assumes that no date has a four-digit year e.g. 01/01/2008

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thank you @digEmAll. Luckily my dataset of around 800 rows had dates none with a four-digit year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
as.Date(paste0(rta$date.of.death, "/08"), "%d/%m/%y")
```

giving

```
[1] "2008-12-12" "2008-10-01" "2008-03-04" "2008-05-24" "2008-04-23"
[6] "2008-11-11" "2008-12-01"
```

Comment: This solution also worked. Like magic, in a **single line code**. Thank you.